# How does Angular find auxiliary router-outlet tags to use

Tags: angular, angular-routing

While I was experimenting with adding auxiliary routes to my application for showing popup windows and wizards, I had some trouble getting angular to actually recognize my named `router-outlet` tag. I had placed it inside of a component that was *not* being routed to, but was instead just inside of a routed-to component. Every time I tried to navigate to the correct route, I would get a message like `Cannot find router outlet popup...` I moved the `router-outlet` up a level in the component hierarchy, and all of a sudden everything was working fine.

So the question is, how exactly does angular parse the component tree to find `router-outlet` tags to add a component to?

Answer (score 0):

The router-outlet registers itself on the parent `RouterOutletMap` (`parentOutletMap`) when it is created

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/52be848f94a70feffd44a1d688286f750d0471d9/modules/%40angular/router/src/directives/router_outlet.ts#L52

```
@Directive({selector: 'router-outlet'})
export class RouterOutlet implements OnDestroy {
  ...    
  constructor(
      private parentOutletMap: RouterOutletMap, private location: ViewContainerRef,
      private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, @Attribute('name') private name: string) {
    parentOutletMap.registerOutlet(name ? name : PRIMARY_OUTLET, this);
  }
```

Comment: Interesting, what would cause angular not to find the router-outlet then? Being registered in the wrong outletMap? Is it some combination of which module the route is defined in vs where the router-outlet is placed?

Comment: Can you reproduce in a Plunker?